# Getting the actual dropped UIElement object on Drop Event in UWP

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, uwp

I'm converting an application I wrote in WinForms to UWP and as far as I can tell, the Drag n Drop functionality is slightly different.  Here is my code from my WinForms application that I used to get the 'dragged' object, which is a Control called FunctionButton;

```
private void flowLayoutPanel_ActiveGroup_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Function_Button draggedItem;

    /* Check if the dragged item is one of the allowed dragged item TYPES. */
    draggedItem = (Function_Button)e.Data.GetData(type);

    if (draggedItem != null)
    {
       //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

I'm currently setting my own StringDataFormats when the Drag Starts for the information i need, which I read using DataView.GetDataAsync(), although how can I get direct access to the dragged UIElement object in UWP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way but it works.

First you need to handle the `DragStarting` event and store the `UIElement` that will be dragged inside the `DataPackage` that is exposed by the `Data` property. The `DataPackage` type seems to be very conditioned on files and file formats but fortunately it has a general purpose dictionary exposed by property `Properties`.

```
<local:YourElement CanDrag="True" DragStarting="dragStarting">

</local:YourElement>

private void dragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
{
   args.Data.Properties.Add("anykeyworks", sender);
}
```

Next you handle the Drop event as follows:

```
<local:YourOtherElement AllowDrop="True" DragOver="dragOver" Drop="drop">

</<local:YourOtherElement>

private void drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   UIElement element = e.DataView.Properties["anykeyworks"] as UIElement;
}

private void dragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
}
```

If you do not implement the DragOver handler, the Drop event won't be fired.

Comment: Great workaround but unfortunately this doesn't work for me if I want to keep this in the UI code seperate from the DataPackage. Well I guess hacky code it is. That seems to be the way to go in UWP.

Answer (score -1):

As you've known, the drag and drop function in UWP is different from what in WinForms. In UWP apps, what we are dragging and dropping is not the [**UIElement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) but the [**DataPackage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.aspx). So we can't get direct access to the dragged `UIElement` object.

I'm not sure why you want to get the dragged or dropped `UIElement` object. If you want to do some checks while dropping, I think you can check the content of the [DataPackageView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.aspx) which is exposed by [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.drageventargs.dataview) property.

For more information about drag and drop function in UWP, please see [Drag and drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop) and also the official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) on GitHub.

Comment: Why would I want to know that? Maybe to prevent an item from being dragged onto itself? Which seems to be possible even though the original item actually invisible while dragging. And apparently I can't even fix that. Great job Microsoft.

Comment: As I've said, we can't get direct access to the dragged UIElement object. But you can always check the content of the `DataPackageView` class which is exposed by `DataView` property. @Frank Rem's answer just did this. It got the `UIElement` by using `e.DataView.Properties["anykeyworks"]`.

Comment: I know. I found a bug which makes it so that when I'm dragging something from a GridView, I can drop it onto itself (its original placeholder, which is invisible - obviously an unexpected behavior). You might want to fix your bugs before shipping your software. But I'm already dealing with like 2 different bugs right now This is not something unusual, this is what I call Tuesday. Literally everything riddled with bugs, I've never seen anything like this. You always have to do hacks and workarounds of workarounds. It's almost like nobody actually uses UWP.

Comment: If I were to report every single one of them, it would have to be my full-time job just reporting bugs.